# jQuery Mobile only for the menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile site and I would like to implement jQuery data-roles and other nice to haves only on the menu.

Is it possible to adapt the jQuery library to work only on the menu and leave every other website navigation "normal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the option `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true` in the jQuery Mobile configuration file, or in the head of your HTML file - this option shall be set before loading JQM:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you can put `rel=external` in the anchor tag - the link will load without ajax and your url will *"navigate normal"*:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" rel="external" />Link without ajax</a>
```

Here you will find the JQM documentation about this topic:

https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/